# Non-EU Dutch resident (Indian citizen), working in Belgium

Tags: netherlands, belgium

I am a non-EU citizen from India, residing in the Netherlands for more than 5 years now. The resident permit for the first 4 years was sponsored by the University where I carried out my PhD, and since then, I have a dependent visa on my husband, who works in the Netherlands.

I now have an offer to work in Belgium and I would like to take it up. I would like to keep my residence in the Netherlands and travel daily to work, especially since my partner is working in the Netherlands and I want to apply for PR in the Netherlands.

As a non-EU citizen can I get a cross-border commuter working contract? Will I pay my taxes in the Netherlands or in Belgium? Which country will provide healthcare, unemployment, family benefits, and pension?

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible to the setup that you draw. You might open Dutch company that employs only you and make a contract between it and BE company. After that, you will be still tax resident for NL and all your conditions will be fulfilled. That might be also preferable for BE company since they will hire you on a freelance basis.

Comment: @EugenMartynov I don't see the point or how that would help in any way.

Comment: @Gala, I also don't see the problem. Opening the company or going to one of umbrella companies in the Netherlands will satisfy all requirements from topic starter.

Comment: Some info [here](https://www.maastrichtuniversity.nl/sites/default/files/crossborder_work_living_abroad_while_working_nl_belgium.pdf).

Comment: Hi Eugen, Thanks for your reply. I am already a tax resident in NL. I paid taxes while working as a PhD researcher. And now I am tax partner of my husband.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible scenario. Someone i know had a similar scenario. She had a residence permit in the Netherlands ( based on her husbands work in NL)  and had some kind of work permit in Belgium. She pays taxes in Belgium ( works there), Declaring taxes was a little complex so they had a tax attorney to file taxes for them ( Though i think it was not that difficult). For your PR your residence matters, so if you live in the Netherlands uninterrupted 5 years then you can apply for a PR based on your Husbands permanent work contract. Health insurance you need to take for both countries ( The Belgium one is way cheap anyways). Child benifits you get in the country you reside in ( that is NL), Though in Belgium the child benifits are way more than NL.